# N returns a expression, not a single machine real number

Tags: numerics

I have the expression:

```
expr =
  k^2 p^2 Sin[θ]^2 - k^2(p (k Sin[θ])/k1)^2 - 
  p^2(-k Sin[θ] Sqrt[1 - ((k Sin[θ])/k1)^2] + 
  k Cos[θ] (k Sin[θ])/k1) + 
  p k Cos[θ]2(-k Sin[θ] Sqrt[1-((k Sin[θ])/k1)^2] + 
  k Cos[θ] (k Sin[θ])/k1)(p (k Sin[θ])/k1);
```

where

```
k1 = Sqrt[p^2+k^2-2p k Cos[θ]];
```

Next I do

```
z6 = ExpandAll[expr];
k = 100; 
θ = Pi/3;
z6 /. p -> 100
```

and I get

[image]

I try to put the result into numerical form in this way:

```
% // N
```

and I get

[image]

But I need a one-number answer. Where may my error be?

Comment: That is not what I get. I get zero.   ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Igcn.png)  Try to with clean kernel.

Comment: @Nasser Righty, every good notebook begins with an `Exit`. ;o)

Comment: @Nasser, `p->0` is a root of `expr==0`. Not important in this context, but I want to comment because I am bored  :/ .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing; I suspect it is being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.

Comment: Wolfram Community [crosspost](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1253781)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `p` has been given a value earlier in your notebook. Then you might get the kind of result you are seeing because `expr` gets evaluated before you substitute `p -> 100` into it.

```
p = 42;
expr /. {k -> 100, p -> 100, θ -> Pi/3}
```

[image: result]

However, both

```
p = 42;
Clear[p]
expr /. {k -> 100, p -> 100, θ -> Pi/3}
```

and

```
p = 42;
Block[{k = 100, p = 100, θ = Pi/3}, expr]
```

will work and give the result `0`.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for answers!

I found my mistake. I don't understand, why, but it was in real code, that I used in my notebook:

    z6=ExpandAll[k^2 p^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2-k^2(p (k Sin[\[Theta]])/k1)^2-p^2(-k Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[1-((k Sin[\[Theta]])/k1)^2]+k Cos[\[Theta]] (k Sin[\[Theta]])/k1)+p k Cos[\[Theta]]2(-k Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[1-((k Sin[\[Theta]])/k1)^2]+k Cos[\[Theta]] (k Sin[\[Theta]])/k1)(p (k Sin[\[Theta]])/k1)]